# Using blob in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, blob, node-pdfkit

I have a project in which i have to provide the user with a pdf generated using pdfkit and allowing users to download the same using blob. I am getting an error on doing so. Any help would be appreciated.
error-

```
TypeError: Blob is not a function
at BlobStream.toBlob (C:\Users\ws\node_modules\blob-stream\index.js:33:18)

Code Snippet:
var doc = new report();
var blobStream = require('blob-stream');
var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
doc.text('And here is some wrapped text...', 100, 300)
  .font('Times-Roman', 13)
  .moveDown()
  .text('lorem', {
     width: 412,
     align: 'justify',
     indent: 30,
     columns: 2,
     height: 300,
     ellipsis: true
});

doc.end();
stream.on('finish',function(){
blob = stream.toBlob('Blob/pdf');

});
```

Comment: Are there any further information? If yes, edit your question!

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `blob.js` (or `blob/index.js`) somewhere in your project? It may be interfering with a requirement of `blob-stream` (called [`blob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob)).

Comment: yes i have blob-stream installed in that folder